# Data Execution Prevention problem in Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, windows

I am an ASP.NET developer, who has minimal knowledge in Server administration.
I have a database hosted at Windows Server 2008.
Today morning onwards it periodically stops working.
The message given is something to the effect
"The program is being shut down to prevent Data Execution Prevention error"
Some other programs are also showing the behavior.

I would like to know, what causes this all of a sudden?
The server is UN-protected(IE: no anti-virus installed at all), could this be a possible anti-virus/ malware attack?
What do we need to do to get the SOL running smoothly again?

Regards,
Naveen Jose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naveen - Is it the application that you have written, which is being shut down by DEP?

If so, have you recently updated the application in any way, or were there no changes to it at the time this problem began?

If it's a change in the code that you have made, that started all of this off, then you need to read up on [what DEP is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Execution_Prevention) and how it works, and take the necessary steps to fix your code.

I wouldn't recommend disabling DEP to fix this issue any more than I would recommend disabling your firewalls because you're having problems with a port connection.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips for your problem :

http://www.win2008workstation.com/win2008/disable-data-execution-prevention

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff542275%28VS.85%29.aspx